# C `SIGVTALRM` is not handled when `sigwait` or `pause`

Tags: c, multithreading, timer, signals, posix

Referencing the code provided at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html under the *Program source* section.

Changes to that code are: **1)** `SIGVTALRM` is blocked instead of `SIGQUIT` & `SIGUSR1`, **2)** a timer is set up with `setitimer(2)` after the comment section (`/* Main thread carries on to create other threads and/or do other work */`).

Signals other than `SIGVTALRM` appears to be handled properly (such as `SIGINT`, even `SIGALRM`) if we use `pause(2)` (as is the case in the sample code) or `sigwait(3)`. `SIGVTALRM` is only handled correctly when the main thread busy-wait using `while(1);` (replacing `pause();` in the sample code).

It looks like `ITIMER_VIRTUAL` is not decremented at all (note that this is just my suspicion). Why is this the case? Is there a way to fix this while still using timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send `SIGVTALRM` with `kill`, it should arrive just fine. The problem is not signal delivery but that you misunderstand what "virtual time" means. None passes while your thread is sleeping/blocked waiting for something, so the timer will never expire. Perhaps you wanted real rather than virtual time.